# Error rebasing: non existing untracked files would be overwritten

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to squash a few commits into a single one. The changes made involve changing file contents, as well as only changing the filename case on some files or their directories.

When running `git status`,

```
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

However, when I `rebase -i <sha>`,

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        myDir/file1
        myDir/file2
        ...
        myDir/fileN
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

At some point in the history of commits I'm trying to squash, `myDir` was renamed to `MyDir`

However, none of those files are actually on my disk. Running `ls` shows the new `MyDir`, but no `myDir`.

How can I fix this so I can rebase?

fyi, `ignorecase = false` in `.git/config` under `[core]` and I'm on Mac OSX

Comment: It's probable that moving the `myDir` directory out of the way will allow the `git rebase --continue` to happen.

Comment: What kind of OS do you have and what kind of filesystem is this?  You mention `core.ignorecase`, but is the underlying filesystem actually case sensitive?  It looks like it's _not_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `core.ignorecase` setting is Git's way of keeping track of *how your operating system actually behaves*.  If Git can create a file named `README`, and then open it using the name `readme`, your OS's file system *is* case-insensitive.  This means your OS *can't* create *two separate files* whose name differs only in case.

That applies to directories as well.  If `MyDir` exists, Git's attempt to create `myDir` to hold files named `myDir/file1` and so on will fail (in a way Git considers mostly harmless, namely that the directory already exists), because the OS will just use the existing `MyDir`.  Git's attempt to write `myDir/file1` will then overwrite the `MyDir/file1` file.  If those files currently contain valuable data, you will want to move them out of the way, just as Git suggests.  In any case you will probably want to move the entire *directory* `MyDir` out of the way so that Git can create one spelled `myDir` (lowercase `m`).

If your operating system / file-system really, truly is *not* case insensitive—if you *can* create different files all named `README`, `readme`, `ReadMe`, and so on—you can change the `core.ignorecase` setting to inform Git of this fact.  However, if your system is case insensitive, changing that would be lying to Git, which would be a bad idea.

Comment: My first time ever using a Mac, and assumed the OS was case sensitive, turns out it's not. Very useful test: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/85574

Comment: The Mac file systems default to this, but you can make one that is fully case-sensitive if you need to. I'm pretty sure they still do UTF-8 normalization though (causing problems with combining vs non-combining spellings).